# Анимация на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Скажите пожалуйста! Как можно сделать так чтобы объект одновременно вместе с подъемом вверх исчезал? В моем коде получается что, объект  достигает определенной точки и только потом исчезает.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text1").delay(8000).animate({left:"+=240px"}, 3000).delay(2500).animate({top:"-=30px"}, 1000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text1").delay(8000).animate({left:"+=240px"}, 3000).delay(2500).animate({top:"-=30px", opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
```

так он исчезает когда движется вверх =)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь!